# How do I calculate the x value that corresponds to the mean density of a continuous function?

Tags: r

I have a negative exponential dispersal kernel that corresponds to the probability of infection based on distance from the source.

```
theta <- 10
beta <- 10

eq <- function(x) {
  discale <- exp(-x/theta)
  k.norm <- beta*(1/(2*pi*theta^2))
  f <- k.norm*discale
  return(f)
}

ggplot(data.frame(x=c(0, 100)), aes(x=x)) + 
  stat_function(fun=eq) +
  theme_minimal() +
  ylab("Infection Likelihood") +
  xlab("Distance from Source")
```

[image]

What I am trying to calculate is the x value that corresponds to the mean density of the kernel.

So I think I am estimating the mean density of the kernel with this line of code.

```
intpd <- integrate(eq, 0, 100)
intpdm <- intpd$value/100 - 0
```

Which produces a value of 0.001591477. I want to find what that value corresponds to on the x axis.

I am still learning many of the basics in mathematics and programming, so I may be doing something wrong or missing something here. I just need to know what the mean distance is so I can verify what theta means.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `optim` to find the value which minimizes a function. The `x` which minimizes the function `function(x) (eq(x) - intpdm)^2` should be your desired output

```
optim(50, fn = function(x) (eq(x) - intpdm)^2, 
      method = 'Brent', lower = 0, upper = 100)$par
# [1] 23.02631
```

Plotting this confirms the value is correct

```
ggplot(data.frame(x=c(0, 100)), aes(x=x)) + 
  stat_function(fun=eq) +
  theme_minimal() +
  ylab("Infection Likelihood") +
  xlab("Distance from Source") +
  geom_hline(yintercept = intpdm) + 
  geom_vline(xintercept = 23.0263)
```

[image]

Comment: This might be a stupid question, but could you explain to me more how ````function(x) (eq(x) - intpdm)^2```` works to estimate x that "minimizes" it?

Comment: The function `(eq(x) - intpdm)^2` will be at its lowest when `eq(x)` is equal to `intpdm`, because at that point it will be equal to zero (and a square cannot get smaller than zero). In this way, finding the `x` which minimizes  `(eq(x) - intpdm)^2` is equivalent to finding an `x` where `eq(x)` is equal to `intpdm`. Does that answer the question, or were you asking something else?

Comment: To be clear, simply defining the function `function(x) (eq(x) - intpdm)^2` does not estimate an `x` that minimizes it. The minimization is done by putting that function into `optim`, which then does the minimization.

Comment: This answers my question clearly, thank you very much.

Comment: To clarify, has the value of ````intpdm```` confirmed the mean probability density of my curve?

Comment: No, that part is not verified in this code, I took it as an assumption. That being said, your calculation (1/(b - a))*(integral from a to b of f(x)) does give the mean value unless I'm missing something.

Answer (score -2):

I recomand you to express your formula for calculation of your graph as mathematical formula like:

```
f(x) = 1/x
//or
y = 1/x
//you can then modify this formula to get what is x equal to
x * y = 1
x = 1/y
```

if i red your function right your formula is

```
y = (10 * X**10)/(2 * pi * 100)
//so
y * 200 * pi = 10 * X**10
//then
sqrt(y * 20 * pi, 10) = X
```

you have to figure out code your self as i dont know R at all